# The_multi-part_identifier__no__could_not_be_bound

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm executing the following query:

```
UPDATE listas2010
    SET listas2010.price = listas2010_post.price ,
        listas2010.on_hand = listas2010_post.on_hand
    FROM listas2010_post RIGHT JOIN
         listas2010
         ON listas2010.sku = listas2010_post.sku
    WHERE (listas2010_post.list_no = ? AND listas2010.list_no = ? AND listas2010_post.price <> 0)
```

And in my logs it gives me this error

> The multi-part identifier listas2010_post.list_no could not be bound.

Can someone please help with this.

Comment: The column doesn't exist.  There isn't much we can do about that.

Comment: And the `RIGHT JOIN` is actually an Inner Join